# Directory name from path

Tags: c#

with this code

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
```

I am able to get the directories in that path but I get the full path, e.g.:

> C:\Users\test1\Documents\Visual Studio 2010
>   C:\Users\test1\Documents\test
>   C:\Users\test1\Documents\example

How can I get the name of the last directory!?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call [`Path.GetFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to get the last segment of a path.

Comment: Nice. Had always assumed this only gave a file name - reading the docs, absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

If you call

```
DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories(path)
```

you will get an array of DirectoryInfo objects, which have a Name property with the info that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(x => x.Replace(path, "")).ToArray();
```

Do not forget to import `System.Linq`

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
DirectoryInfo path = new DirectoryInfo('path to your folder');
IList<DirectoryInfo> directories = path.GetDirectories();
string last = directories.Last().Name;
```

The `DirectoryInfo` class is nice, because it gives you a little bit more information about the directory than does `Directory.GetDirectories()`;